# Somar histórico

Tags: python

Possuo o dataset chamado gd, tirado de um xls, um exemplo:

```
 DATA_CRIA   FROTA
 1971        2
 1972        19
 1973        19
```

Este dataset possui várias entradas com o padrão listado acima, gostaria de criar um dicionário com os valores de cada anos somados com anteriores, por exemplo:

```
{1971:2, 1972:21, 1973:40}
```

Para isso fiz isto:

```
dic_ano = {}
for ano in anos:
    dic_ano.update({ano:0})

for i in range(len(gd)):
    for ano in anos:
        if gd.iloc[i]['DATA_CRIA'] == ano:
            dic_ano[ano] = dic_ano[ano]+1
```

Mas os valores não estão saindo com a contagem certa, o que devo fazer?

Comment: É isso que deseja? https://repl.it/@marcelobonifazio/RosybrownOrchidMegabyte

Comment: Eu errei na minha explicação, dei a entender que o dataset era somente esste valores, mais ja arrumei.

Comment: tenho que converter os dados para um dicionario, mas os dados não estão em um dicionario.

Comment: Por acaso está utilizando Pandas?

Comment: sim, mais ainda não consegui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Pego os anos
anos = gd['DATA_CRIA'].tolist()
#OU anos = gd['DATA_CRIA'].values

#ordeno os anos por precaução
anos.sort()

dic_ano = {}
soma_frota = 0
for ano in anos:
    #filtro o gd onde DATA_CRIA é igual ao ano, pego o valor da coluna FROTA
    soma_frota += gd[gd['DATA_CRIA'] == ano]['FROTA'].values[0]
    dic_ano.update({ano:soma_frota})

>>> print(dic_ano)
{1971: 2, 1972: 21, 1973: 40}
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas com um problema que esqueci de mencionar, os anos tem que sair em umas  sequencia que já tenho:`anos=
[1980, 1991, 2000, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2025, 2030, 2040]`

Comment: Ah, então é só usar a sua sequência haha